# Sum for array with While loop JS

Tags: javascript, loops, while-loop

I have tried to make a while loop where I add all the numbers of the array to one sum. I keep on getting an endless loop. I've also tried to do (array.length) (array.length --) (array.length>numbers)
But nothing I tried worked... any suggestions? :)

```
function sumNumbersWhileLoop(array, sum) {
  array = [1, 5, 4, 6, 7];
  sum = 0;
  for (let numbers of array) {
    while (array.length>0) {
      sum += numbers;

      console.log(sum);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: You are repeating while array has a length. You never reduce length of the array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need the `while` loop. The `for...of` loop is going to iterate over the array till its length.

```js
function sumNumbersWhileLoop(array, sum) {
  array = [1, 5, 4, 6, 7];
  sum = 0;
  for (let numbers of array) {
      sum += numbers;
  }
  console.log(sum)
}

sumNumbersWhileLoop();
```

If you want to use while, or `reduce`, then you can do the following:

```js
function sumNumbersWhileLoop() {
  const array = [1, 5, 4, 6, 7];
  let len = array.length - 1;
  let sum = 0;
  while (len >=0) {
    sum += array[len--];
  }
  console.log(sum);

  // Or use reduce :
  const reduceSum = array.reduce((acc, item) => acc + item, 0);
  console.log(reduceSum);
}

sumNumbersWhileLoop();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
function sum(arr, sum) {
    arr = [1, 5, 4, 6, 7];
    sum = 0;
    while (arr.length > 0) {
        sum += arr.pop();
    }
    return sum;
}
console.log(sum());
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved by adding more information on what the code does and how it helps the OP.